# Errors while changing "passwd" in openwrt

Tags: openwrt, passwd

I am using ext4 as my root file system. I am using OpenWRT Chaos Calmer. When I change the passwd, I see the following error sometimes:

```
root@US16SIQC:~# passwd 
Changing password for root
New password: 
Bad password: too short
Retype password: 

passwd: can't create '/etc/passwd+': File exists
passwd: can't update password file /etc/passwd
```

These things happen sometimes only. What is the fix for this?

Whenever I change the passwd, it creates passwd+ and passwd- files. I undersatnd that passwd+ file gets copied into passwd file and passwd- is a backup file. So when the first error came, this file still exists.

Please help on this. Thanks in advance!!

[EDIT]: I Fixed the read-only filesystem problem, but still see the issue.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Change passwd (Passwd changed successfully)
2. Observe that there is no `passwd+` file in `/etc`
3. Do a hard power reboot
4. Observed that `passwd+` is exists under `/etc`
5. Now I cannot change it unless I remove the `passwd+` file

This happens only by hard reboot, not by soft reboot.

I am using imx6dl based custom board with eMMC flash containing two partitions-one `vfat(zImage and dtb)` and other `etx4(rootfs)`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I wasn't able to set a password for root. The file was read-only. There were some mounting error logs while the system was booting. The problem solved by re-installing the OpenWRT. Apparently, it was a file system issue.

Comment: Actually you don't even need to re-install per-se, this just cropped here on `Chaos Calmer` and you just have to, all inside Luci, make a backup of the configuration, reset the fs and then restore the backup. A minor nuissance, but still.

Answer (score 0):

OpenWRT is not installed correctly.

Usually, this happens when the overlay file system is not initialised properly.

```
root@OpenWrt:~# df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs                     320       232        88  73% /
/dev/root                 2560      2560         0 100% /rom
tmpfs                    14504        96     14408   1% /tmp
/dev/mtdblock3             320       232        88  73% /overlay
overlayfs:/overlay         320       232        88  73% /
tmpfs                      512         0       512   0% /dev
```

If you run `df` at `root` prompt, you should see `overlays:/overlay` filesystem mounted on `/`.

One of the possible causes is trying to install image bigger than the flash. Or, probably the reboot after installation was interrupted.

Comment: I don't seem to have a `overlay fs` at all. I do not even have `mtdblock` as well

Comment: When is hardware and openwrt release you are using?

Comment: You mean `which hardware`?. I am using a imx6dl based custom board with OpenWRT chaos calmer

Comment: Did you build your own image? What is the flash size?. I suppose you have atleast 8mb flash.

Comment: I have an eMMC flash of 4GB

Comment: I am generating an image out of openwrt-rootfs.tar, dtb, uboot.img and zImage

Comment: Watch out for output on serial console out on first boot. You may see errors about overlay filesystem

Comment: I will check that, but how do I know that `reboot after installation was interrupted`

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same behavior on a different embedded linux system.  I found that by resetting the password and immediately power cycling, the issue would crop up.

Looking into busybox's implementation, I found that the `/etc/passwd+` file is a temp file for the new changes.  Once it has been successfully written with the new changes, it is moved back to `/etc/passwd`

So the presense of `/etc/passwd+` indicates the previous iteration failed in some way, either with a power cycle before it could be moved (or removed), or a filesystem error of sorts (a lot can happen in that regard on an embedded system like power glitches, full filesystem, corrupt NAND flash, over-temperature, etc.)

The busybox implementation will error out if the file already exists:

From `libbb/update_passwd.c`

```
123     /* Try to create "/etc/passwd+". Wait if it exists. */
124     i = 30;
125     do {
126         // FIXME: on last iteration try w/o O_EXCL but with O_TRUNC?
127         new_fd = open(fnamesfx, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600);
128         if (new_fd >= 0) goto created;
129         if (errno != EEXIST) break;
130         usleep(100000); /* 0.1 sec */
131     } while (--i);
132     bb_perror_msg("can't create '%s'", fnamesfx);
133     goto close_old_fp;
```